# SAS use Forrmat to create a new variable

Tags: sas, informat

I am thinking a question: How to create a new variable by using informat.
like : we have a informat like that:

```
proc format ;
 invalue  $agegrpcd   
               1 = '<18'
               2 = '18 - 29'
               3 = '30 - 39'
               4 = '40 - 49'
               5 = '50 - 65'
               6 = '> 65'
               . = 'Missing' ;run;
```

and a dataset like that:

```
data age;
    input age 4. ;
    cards;
    22
    34
    13
    45
    64
    33
    ;run;
```

now I want to have a dataset like this:

```
age  agegroup
15  <18
25   18 - 29
33   30 - 39
45   40 - 49
64   50 - 65
77   > 65
```

Is there any way to put the numeric variable age into the character variable agegroup by using the informat I built?
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you need to alter your PROC Format statement and create a format, not an informat.

```
proc format ;
value  agegrpcd   
           0-17 = '<18'
           18-29 = '18 - 29'
           30-39 = '30 - 39'
           40-49 = '40 - 49'
           50-65 = '50 - 65'
           66-high = '> 65'
           . = 'Missing' ;
run;
```

After that, use the PUT() function to convert the number to the character string.

```
data age;
set age;
agegroup=put( age, agegrpcd8.);
run;
```

Comment: Agree.  Key point is that OP needs to create a format, not an informat.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks.  I clarified to ensure that point was understood.

Comment: Thank you so mach OP. It is very helpful.  But now I want to store the character ( <18,  18 - 29) in the new variable "agegroup"  and not just mask it.

Comment: You are not masking it.  You are creating a character variable holding the format string.  Run the code and look at the columns.